# Do not log my own visits with a tracking pixel (web beacon)

Tags: apache, email, logging, user-agent

I'm adding a tracking pixel at then end of the emails I send via Gmail:

```html
<img src="http://myserver.com/test/1pixelimage.png?id=track_emailSentToBob" />
```

and then I have a script on my server which **sends me a notification via email** when Apache sees `1pixelimage.png?id=track_*` in the logs. It works perfectly.

**Problem**: I receive a notification each time I open my own email in Gmail's `Sent` folder.

I've thought about:

- filter by IP: *not working* because I often Gmail on phone, which has a dynamic IP, changing very often.
- filter by UserAgent (that I could customize, e.g. I could set user agent = blabla, and send me notifications only if user agent is NOT blabla): this would require that I install a UserAgent modifier extension on all my browsers (not possible on phone), so *this is not a solution*.
- anyway, when opening an email in Gmail, Gmail caches the images, so the request would not be done by my own browser but by Gmail's image caching server

**How would you filter out your own visits of the tracking pixel image?**

Note: I don't want to use a third-party app that requires *"Send, write, manage your emails"* permissions on Gmail.

Comment: What does the HTTP `referer` [sic] look like in your apache httpd logs?  Maybe you can use that?

Comment: See also [web beacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_beacon)

Comment: I do not know about Gmail since I do not use it, but any kind of good webmail (mine does) should be able to offer you the opportunity to selectively load (or not) images referenced in the email. If that is available in GMail, configure it not to load images for email coming to you from your specific email adress and then the beacon should not be hit at all. Or more low-tech: move the message into a folder where you are sure not to open it again.

Comment: For mobile maybe have a 'trigger' resource that only you can load, that the script detects and then ignores log lines from the same user agent and/or ip for a set period after the trigger (or have an 'untrigger' resource). For as long as your IP stays constant it will work ok and if the IP changes, the fallback to user agent will stop it recording yours but may lead to some genuine opens being ignored. It depends which is more important and how long you would need the set period to be. Don't know about the google cache, your trigger could be a special email to try to capture *that* IP.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek you cannot do that in Gmail web client, sadly. About the low-tech solution: I want to be able to re-open my own emails often (for reference) without triggering a new notification to be sent.

Comment: @TroyWray yes in fact IP solution doesn't work at all, since it's Google image-caching server's IP which is used (changes very often).

Comment: Can you change the id= part of the email that is specifically sent to you and change your script on server side to not send a notification if it sees your specific id accessing it?

Comment: That's an idea @PatrickMevzek: I wish I could do this.

Comment: If you control neither the script sending the email nor the script doing the notification nor the webmail you use, then I fear your problem is without solutions... Low tech again: can't you just ignore the useless notification you get yourself, including having a rule in your webmail to discard them automatically? It does not resolve the core of your problem though, but again any good webmail should be able to provide you such feature.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek About the low tech solution: yes I could filter them but how could i distinguish my own notifications from those generated by the recipient? That's the problem! They both appear in the logs as "Google caching server required this image" // I do control the script sending email (using Sendgrid SMTP), but if I want a different ID sent to myself, then it will look like this in my inbox `From:myself@gmail.com To: myself@gmail.com` which is bad (because then I don't see the original recipient). I would prefer `From:myself@gmail.com To:recipient@yahoo.com Bcc:myself@gmail.com`

Comment: `you cannot do that in Gmail web client, sadly.` Apparently you can do that. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919

Comment: @Kul-Tigin yes but then it will disable image loading by default for all mails...

Comment: Well, that was the intenton :) I couldn't understand why an email sent as BCC to you from Sendgrid is on your Gmail's Sent folder. Do you have a rule to move it there? Or do you use Gmail's SMTP with your account's credentials to send emails? I'm asking because there might be a Sendgrid solution.

Comment: @kul-tigin this might be a solution (prevent Gmail to load images from my own emails), I'm testing this this evening :)

Answer (score -1):

Do it the way you prevent tracking pixels from others, too. Disable HTML-Mail in your mail programs and adblock tracking pixels in your browser for webmail.

If the gmail app does not allow this, get another e-mail app. Loading content linked in a e-mail is a bad idea anyway. If you want an easy example, then think of read receipts for spammers ...

On the other hand: Why do you want to track others? They will be as annoyed as you, because they like their privacy as well.